# How to include urls with app_name without having to use reverse with app name in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have a custom directory for `allauth` templates. I need some custom `urlpatterns` as well as I don't want some default views. I wanted to start with glueing in the entire `allauth` and change things that I need later on.

My main app `config/urls.py` file

```py
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path("account/", include("users.urls")),
]
```

Users app:

`users/urls.py`

```py
app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    path("login/", allauth_views.login, name="account_login"),
    path("logout/", allauth_views.logout, name="account_logout"),
    path("signup/", allauth_views.signup, name="account_signup"),
]
```

With this basic setup, if I go to `/account/login` it routes correctly to the desired view, but it is defined in `users` app with the `app_name = "users"`, therefore, I have to access it in other views with `reverse(users:account_login)`. The problem is that `allauth` `LoginView` has this method

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(self.request,
                                                   reverse("account_signup"),
                                                   self.redirect_field_name)
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request,
                                                 self.redirect_field_name)
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        ret.update({"signup_url": signup_url,
                    "site": site,
                    "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                    "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value})
        return ret
```

which does the lookup on `reverse("account_signup")` but Django gets lost and throws `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch`.

Two solutions:

1. If I set those `allauth` urlpatterns in my main urls file it works correctly but I want to keep this file small and define `allauth` urls in my `users` app.
2. If I don't define `app_name` in my `users/urls.py` it works properly but I want it for other routes. I consider adding `app_name` to be a good practice. I could have created another app for `allauth` without an app name but then I'd have users stuff in two apps.

None of these satisfy me.

What I want:

Can I somehow `include` them without a namespace? I tried `path("account/", include("users.urls", namespace=None))` without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't thinking... I can keep my custom `users` urls in `users/urls.py` with an app name and create another urls file like `users/allauth_urls.py` in `users` app and things work correctly.

Then, with

```
    path("account/", include("users.allauth_urls")),
```

Things work as exepcted.